# WP Rest-API response is unauthorized (React)

Tags: plugins, authentication, react

I am using trying to fetch data from wp to react via rest api.
There are two API's I am working upon. First one is wp/v2/pages is working fine (With credentials it is authorized) but,

Second api wp/v2/menu-items or wp/v2/menus both are showing that you are not allowed to view this content (Even I am using the same credentials for authorization.

[image: See Image Here]

Comment: Who are you authenticated as? Are you authenticated as an admin?

Comment: Well I am new in case of WP, I am using WP Rest-Api in React, So I dont know how to know whether I am an admin or user. But I am using admin credentials so yes authenticating as an Admin.

Comment: "*First one is wp/v2/pages is working fine (With credentials it is authorized)*" - are you sure you're actually authenticated, or that the credentials were sent along with your request? "*using the same credentials for authorization*" - from where or how did you get that Token? Is it the Application Passwords section at `wp-admin/profile.php`, i.e. the page for editing *your own* profile?

Comment: The image shown is a plugin for auth and i used jwt auth in that, in postman i tried with basic auth using pwd and username it is working for /v2/pages but not for /v2/menus.

Comment: So, you used your WordPress password? But anyway, try using cURL command line with an application password instead - go to the Profile admin page to generate an application password, then try with: `curl https://your-domain/wp-json/wp/v2/menus -u "YOUR USERNAME:YOUR APPLICATION PASSWORD"`

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy, It worked.